# Combine dimensions of lists of lists into separate vectors

Tags: r, list, merge, tidyverse

Here's an example of my data.

```
ll <- list(
  ll1 = list(Mi = 1:4,
       Mj = 10:13,
       dn = "l1"),
  ll2 = list(Mi = 5:8,
             Mj = 14:17,
             dn = "l2"))
> str(ll)
List of 2
 $ ll1:List of 3
  ..$ Mi: int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  ..$ Mj: int [1:4] 10 11 12 13
  ..$ dn: chr "l1"
 $ ll2:List of 3
  ..$ Mi: int [1:4] 5 6 7 8
  ..$ Mj: int [1:4] 14 15 16 17
  ..$ dn: chr "l2"
```

I'm trying to combine each Mi, each Mj, and each dn together. So the final result will be 3 vectors: 1 combined Mi, 1 combined Mj, and 1 combined dn. I.e., the final result for Mi would be something like

```
> c(ll$ll1$Mi,ll$ll2$Mi)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Similar final results for Mj and dn. I'm wondering how to do this simply, preferably using something from tidyverse. The number of lists will vary and won't be 2 generally, which is why I don't think c is a great solution. I am guessing the map functions can work here, but I have not yet found a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `pmap` from `purrr`. `pmap` takes a list of inputs (in this case a list of two lists) and apply the `c` function to `ll[[1]][[1]]`, `ll[[2]][[1]]`, ... then `ll[[1]][[2]]`, `ll[[2]][[2]]`, ... and so on:

```
library(purrr)
pmap(ll, c)
```

**Output:**

```
$Mi
ll11 ll12 ll13 ll14 ll21 ll22 ll23 ll24 
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 

$Mj
ll11 ll12 ll13 ll14 ll21 ll22 ll23 ll24 
  10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17 

$dn
 ll1  ll2 
"l1" "l2"
```

If we don't want to keep the vector names, we can use the `use.names` argument in `c`:

```
pmap(ll, c, use.names = FALSE)
```

**Output:**

```
$Mi
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$Mj
[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17

$dn
[1] "l1" "l2"
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Is there a way to do this without keeping the vector names (ll11, ll12, and so on)? My real dataset is quite large, so keeping the names is adding a large amount of memory. Names can be removed with `llc <- map(llc, unname)` but I'm curious if it can be done in the single pmap line.

Comment: @drj3122 Actually, I take that back. It is as simple as supplying `use.names = FALSE` to the `c` function. I've almost forgotten about this argument.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `purrr::transpose` and `unlist`. This would give you a list of three vectors:

```
purrr::transpose(ll) %>% lapply(unlist)

$Mi
ll11 ll12 ll13 ll14 ll21 ll22 ll23 ll24 
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 

$Mj
ll11 ll12 ll13 ll14 ll21 ll22 ll23 ll24 
  10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17 

$dn
 ll1  ll2 
"l1" "l2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option.

```
library(tidyverse)

groups <- names(ll$ll1)

ll2 <- map(groups, ~unlist(map(ll, .x)))

names(ll2) <- groups

ll2
# $`Mi`
# ll11 ll12 ll13 ll14 ll21 ll22 ll23 ll24 
# 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 
# 
# $Mj
# ll11 ll12 ll13 ll14 ll21 ll22 ll23 ll24 
# 10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17 
# 
# $dn
# ll1  ll2 
# "l1" "l2"
```